# Can you list missing IBOutlets in an Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, iboutlet, pbxproj

Is there a tool that would automatically find out if there are any missing IBOutlets before it causes a runtime crash?

Comment: You can look at the declaration of the IBOutlet and check whether the circle to the left is filled. Means that you connection is set.

Comment: Granted. Is it possible to automate this and make it robust?

Comment: Not automated, but you can NSAssert/assert all of your outlets...